# Reading dictionary from file, modifying, then writing to new file. Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm working on a school assignment that asks me to:

1. Take my previously created dictionary and write it to a file as a string.
2. Then import that dictionary to python again and invert it
3. Write the inverted dictionary to a new file.

I'm having some issues...

The write2file function works fine and creates a text file with the dictionary. But when it comes time to pull it back in and invert the data I get a Type error complaining that string indices must be integers. I am lost. Any help understanding would be appreciated.

I am new to python. Please be gentle :) Thanks in advance for helping me understand what I am doing wrong.

```
<pre><code> 

import os

ChessPlayerProfile = {
    "Matt": [("Rating: ", 2200), ("FIDE ID: 0147632DF"), ("Member Status: ", True)],
    "Will": [("Rating: ", 2200), ("FIDE ID: 3650298MK"), ("Member Status: ", False)],
    "Jithu": [("Rating: ", 1900), ("FIDE ID: 5957200LH"), ("Member Status: ", True)],
    "Lisa": [("Rating: ", 2300), ("FIDE ID: 7719328CX"), ("Member Status: ", False)],
    "Nelson": [("Rating: ", 2500), ("FIDE ID: 6499012XX"), ("Member Status: ", True)],
    "Miles": [("Rating: ", 1600), ("FIDE ID: 4392251TJ"), ("Member Status: ", True)],
}


def write2file():
    with open("chessdict.txt", "w") as f:  # Open file using context manager for memory safety
        f.write(str(ChessPlayerProfile))   # dumping dict to file
                                           # (wanted to use pickle but we need strings per instructions)


def Read_Invert_Write():
    with open("chessdict.txt", "r") as f:       # Read File 1
        TempContent = f.read()                  # assign to temp variable
        invert(TempContent)                     # Invert contents of temp variable
        with open("new_dict.txt", "w") as f:    # create File 2
            f.write(str(TempContent))           # and write new dict from variable contents


def invert(d):                             # Previous function for inverting the dict
    inverse = dict()
    for key in d:                          # Iterate through the list that is saved in dict
        val = d[key]
        for item in val:                   # Check if in the inverted dict the key exists
            if item not in inverse:
                inverse[item] = [key]      # If not then create a new list
            else:
                inverse[item].append(key)
    return inverse


def main():
    write2file()
    Read_Invert_Write()
main()

    </pre></code>
```

Output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/vigz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/copytest.py", line 44, in 
        main()
      File "/home/vigz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/copytest.py", line 43, in main
        Read_Invert_Write()
      File "/home/vigz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/copytest.py", line 15, in Read_Invert_Write
        invert(TempContent)
      File "/home/vigz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/copytest.py", line 32, in invert
        val = d[key]
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a file `f` created like you have:

```
with open("chessdict.txt", "r") as f:
```

the result of `f.read()` is an `str`, not a `dict`. As a result, when you call `invert(f.read())`, this:

```
for d in key:
    val = key[d]
```

is essentially iterating over the *characters* in `f.read()` and attempting to fetch `f.read()[character]` (which is not a valid operation). Concretely, if the content of `chessdict.txt` is:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

the iteration in `invert(f.read())`:

```
inverse = dict()
for key in d:
```

is executing as:

```
inverse = dict()
for key in '{"foo": "bar"}':  # Returns '{', '"', 'f', ...
```

If `chessdict.txt` contains a JSON-encoded string, you can try:

```
import json

with open("chessdict.txt", "r") as f:
    invert(json.load(f))
```

which will return a `dict` if the contents of `f` can be unmarshalled into a JSON. At this point, you might as well rewrite `invert` so that it iterates over keys *and* values:

```
def invert(d):
    inverse = dict()
    for key, value in d.items():
        for item in val:
            ...
```

When it's time to *write* the dictionary to a file, you should avoid `str(your_dictionary)`: if you want to take it into a JSON-encoded string, you should write:

```
with open(your_output_file, "w+") as f:
    json.dump(your_dict, f).
```

This will marshall it into a JSON format correctly (avoiding issues with writing escaped strings like `{\"foo\": ...}` into the file).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you. This has all been very brain twisting for me. I've updated the write2file and Read_Invert_Write functions.

Now I just need to figure out how to rewrite the inverse function to work correctly but I am seeing the issue which is what I asked. Much appreciated.

Comment: Im having a rough time with another area of this program. Would it be "ok" stack overflow etiquette to make a new post about it?

Comment: Yes, you should create a new question if needed, not edit the existing one.